# Why does the following function doesn't detect browser language in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari

I'm using the following function to detect the browser's language:

```
util.getBrowserLang = () => {
  return navigator.languages
    ? navigator.languages[0]
    : (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage)
}
```

It works okay in Chrome and Firefox:

[image]

[image]

But it doesn't get the language in Safari:

[image]

e.g. the function won't return `zh-TW` in the case above.

Why is this? Maybe Safari uses another function to retrieve the browser's language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, Safari doesn't have a `navigator.languages` so the first part of the ternary conditional will never execute on Safari.

That being said, we need to look at `navigator.language`. Intriguingly enough Chrome returns `'en-US'` and Safari returns `'en-us'` when I check it from the browser console. Is it possible your language selector is case-sensitive and isn't detecting the lowercase text? Even though I can't change my localization I imagine it would return `'zh-tw'` instead of `'zh-TW'`. If it helps, you can get a lowercase string by using the `.toLowerCase()` function of the String prototype. You'll need to change your selector's code if you choose to make the string lowercase.